# Problems to start Selenium WebDriver in Maven project

Tags: maven, netbeans, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to run Selenium in a Maven project. Unfortunately the program hangs at the initialization of the `WebDriver` with **no error messages**:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Following things I already tried to fix the problem:

- adding `Selenium-server` as dependency --> **not working**
- adding `Selenium-server-standalone` as dependency --> **not working**
- starting `Selenium-server-standalone` by hand --> **not working**
- adding `Selenium-server-standalone` to the ClassPath (in Eclipse) --> **working**

Even I found a way that my test project is working in Eclipse I still need to run everything with a 'pure' Maven project. This is due the CI integration and furthermore I like to work with Netbeans more than with Eclipse.

Another thing I figured is that everything is working when I use the headless browser (`HtmlUnitDriver`).

Could somebody give me an hint to get everything running with a pure Maven project and a real browser? Thanks in advanced!

- Version Selenium-server: 2.33.0
- Version Selenium-server-standalone: 2.33.0
- Version Firefox: 21
- Version Netbeans: 7.3
- Version Eclipse: Juno Service Release 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use webdriver in maven project. But I use older version of it.
My driver setUp :

```
 protected static WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUp() throws MalformedURLException {
        DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();

        driver = new FirefoxDriver();  //for local check
        driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1920, 1080));
}
```

Dependecies in POM.xml which are resposible for webDriver initialization:

```
 <dependencies>
      <dependency> <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
          <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
          <version>2.29.1</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>4.8.2</version>


      </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: The first dependency in your config (selenium-java) is doing the job. This is written in the documentation too: http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#setting-up-a-selenium-webdriver-project (I should have read it better). Anyway, thank you! The other dependencies are not important to start the browser. Maybe you could edit it?

Comment: Made my answer more concise